# Tkinter frame / canvas not clearing even when destroyed

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a small gui script with tkinter but this issue has been driving me nuts. Here's a minimal example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class EntryView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, prev_view=None, canvas_bg='black', num=1):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.prev_view = prev_view
        self.num = num
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg=canvas_bg)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.left_frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background='')
        self.left_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew')
        
        self.title_label = tk.Label(self.left_frame, text=f"Entry #{self.num}", width=30)
        self.title_label.grid()
        
        self.right_frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, height=200)
        self.right_frame.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=20, pady=20, sticky='ns')

        self.bind('<Left>', self.prev_entry)
        self.bind('<Right>', self.next_entry)

    def next_entry(self, event=None):
        self.grid_remove()
        view = EntryView(self.master, prev_view=self, num=self.num + 1)
        view.grid(sticky='nsew')
        view.focus_set()

    def prev_entry(self, event=None):
        if not self.prev_view:
            return
        self.canvas.delete("all")
        self.grid_remove()
        self.destroy()
        self.prev_view.grid(sticky='nsew')
        self.prev_view.focus_set()


root = tk.Tk()

app = tk.Frame(root)
app.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

entry = EntryView(app, canvas_bg='red')
entry.grid(sticky='nsew')
entry.focus_set()

app.mainloop()
```

The app creates left_frame with transparent background by setting bg=''. It's not technically required here as I could just set the bg color of left_frame to the canvas color, but in my larger application this would not be possible since the canvas contains an image, not a flat color. Pressing the forward arrow key predictably turns the background black. However, navigating backward after that leaves the entire left_frame area under the title label black, even though the entry is destroyed and the previous one restored.

Comment: The issue is due to `background=''` when creating `self.left_frame`.  Try setting `background=canvas_bg` instead.

Comment: @acw1668 I explain in my post why I can't do that, I need transparency.

Comment: According to the official document on [background](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/frame.htm#M6): *"This option is the same as the standard -background option except that its value may also be specified as an empty string. In this case, the widget will display no background or border, and no colors will be consumed from its colormap for its background and border."* My understanding it just don't fill the area of the frame.  That is when the area of the frame is covered by another widget with background color and then that widget is removed, the area of the frame will not be updated.